# Yocto, Fixing Computing transaction error in do_rootfs?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to build the python3 pyinstaller module for custom ARM linux board. The pyinstaller builds correctly and I am able to test it in my board using devtool deploy-target option.

But When creating rootfs it throws the following error.

```
Loading cache...
Updating cache...               ######################################## [100%]

Computing transaction...error: Can't install python3-pyinstaller-1.0-r0@cortexa9hf_neon: no package provides libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0)
```

Here is my recipe file

```
inherit setuptools3
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://PKG-INFO;md5=a06c8045451145c089b1af8542f8f178" 


SRC_URI[md5sum] = "e256bf3f989cb1a1b9a38cef4a187b4c"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "a5a6e04a66abfcf8761e89a2ebad937919c6be33a7b8963e1a961b55cb35986b"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}_append = "already-stripped"

S = "${WORKDIR}/PyInstaller-3.4"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = " python3-altgraph python3-macholib python3-pefile python3-future"

SRC_URI = " \
        https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/32/0e0de593f129bf1d1e77eed562496d154ef4460fd5cecfd78612ef39a0cc/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz \
        file://run \
"
```

Help me to fix this error.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, the package canno't be installed because it needed a library libdl.so. (GLIBC). What happens is you add "glibc" to the RDEPENDS_${PN} variable ?

Comment: I added and the result is same